# Clojure higher order functions

Tags: clojure

I was solving problems in 4clojure and got stuck at [Problem 46](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/46) or example

```lisp
(= true ((__ >) 7 8))
```

where we need to fill in the `_`

Basically I need to create a function that would take in another function as an argument but don't know where to go with that. Also, the evaluation kind of confuses me, if I create an anonymous function

```lisp
(fn [f] ())
```

which takes in the function `>` I don't know how to pass in the other arguments for `>` to operate on.

I don't want the answer, just some direction.

Comment: A couple tips: with a function `f`, you can do `(apply f args)` where args is a list, or `(f arg1 arg2 ...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given what ever you put in the blank will take > and then be evaluated as a function what you need is a function that returns a function.

You have this:

```
 (fn [f] ())
```

How do we get that to return a function?

```
 (fn [f] (fn [something here] (something here)))
```

Now all you have to do is fill out the 'something here's.

Comment: Solved it `(fn [f] (fn [a b] (f b a)))` The returning a function part was a bit confusing initially. Thanks!!

Comment: nice, you can also use `complement` and `partial` - `((complement (partial >)) 7 8)`

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is the one that returns a function that reverses its arguments and applies to the original function:

```
(fn [f]
  (fn [x y]
    (f y x)))
```

Comment: If you click through to the actual problem set he is looking at, that is not right. What they are looking for is a swap the arguments to the given function. One of the other examples is `(= 3 ((__ nth) 2 [1 2 3 4 5]))`